# Array Prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am trying to change the code so that the tests ("if condition (both)) returns true

```js
function X(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

function Y(y) {
  this.y = y;
}

var x = new X(1);
var y = new Y("abc")

if (y instanceof X)
  console.log("true");

if (x instanceof Y)
  console.log("true");
```

This is what I tried so far ,But I am not getting correct result.

```js
function X(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

function Y(y) {
  this.y = y;
}

X.prototype = Object.create(Y.prototype);
X.constructor = X;

var x = new X(1);
var y = new Y("abc");

if (y instanceof X)
  console.log("true");
if (x instanceof Y)
  console.log("true");
```

I am able to change only one object variable .not both.I am trying to both the result to return true.

Comment: Its impossible. You can't have two way inheritance. Thats like you can't be the father of your dad. However you could probably trick out the instanceof operator

Comment: @JonasW.:This Question I took from Book. I really tried hard.They have mentioned you can add some code but your results should return true in both case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said before, the only way is to trick out instanceof:

```
function A(){
   return Object.create(B.prototype);
}

function B(){
   return Object.create(A.prototype);
}
```

That way you have cross inheritance, so all elements created with A inherit from B, and vice versa. [Try it](http://jsbin.com/topaxiboke/edit?console)

Comment: W.Thank you  so much.